# Proof Using Formal Definition of Limit

Tags: calculus

Prove that the limit of sin(x) as it approaches infinity does not exist using the formal definition of a limit.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level. Also, many find the use of imperative ("Prove", "Solve", etc.) to be rude when asking for help; please consider rewriting your post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\epsilon=1$ (or, if you wish, something smaller, like $1/4$). If there was a number $a$ such that $\lim_{x\to\infty} \sin x=a$, then there would be a $B$ such that  $|\sin x-a|\lt \epsilon$ for all $x\gt B$.

But there are arbitrarily large $s$ such that $\sin s=1$, and also arbitrarily large $t$ such that $\sin t=-1$. Show that $a$ cannot be simultaneously at distance $\lt 1$ from $1$ and from $-1$. Formally, this part of the argument uses the Triangle Inequality.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose it does exist and seek a contradiction. It shouldn't be too difficult to find something inconsistent with your proposed limit and the oscillatory nature of sine.

Answer (score 0):

**Suppose that you use the limit of sequence to define the limit of function.**

To prove that $\displaystyle \lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\sin(x)$ does not exist we choose two different real sequences $\{u_n\}$ and $\{v_n\}$ such that
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}u_n=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}v_n=\infty,
$$
and
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sin(u_n)\ne\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sin(v_n).
$$
For example we choose
$$
u_n=\frac{\pi}{2}+n2\pi, \quad v_n=\pi+n2\pi \quad (n\in \mathbb{N}).
$$
Then
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}u_n=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}v_n=\infty,
$$
and
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sin(u_n)=1\ne0=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sin(v_n).
$$